# How does free_shipping conditional work?

Tags: expresso-store

I can't seem to figure out how this works.

`{if free_shipping=="True"} this {if:else} that {/if}`

`{if free_shipping} this {if:else} that {/if}`

`{if free_shipping} this {/if}`

None seem to work, whether I set free shipping on the product, or with a discount.

*edit* And this is in a exp:store:product tag where everything else is working okay.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
{if free_shipping=="1"} Free! {if:else} Not Free!{/if}
```

or

```
{if free_shipping=="1"} Free! {/if}
```

etc...